# RealmSwift logs error even on sample from docs

Tags: ios, swift, database, console, realm

Quick Start from official docs:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/

I just create a sample app with storyboards, connect RealmSwift through Cocoapods and change ViewController's code to the following:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Todo: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
   @Persisted var name: String = ""
   @Persisted var status: String = ""
   @Persisted var ownerId: String
   convenience init(name: String, ownerId: String) {
       self.init()
       self.name = name
       self.ownerId = ownerId
   }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let todo = Todo(name: "Do laundry", ownerId: "user.id")
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(todo)
        }
    }
}
```

The log in console:

```
2023-03-13 11:09:14.269102+0300 TestRealm[56847:824997] Task <E9B2CB4F-27E1-44B6-8F20-9422342C1FDB>.<2> HTTP load failed, 1708/0 bytes (error code: -1017 [4:-1])
2023-03-13 11:09:14.272633+0300 TestRealm[56847:824997] Task <E9B2CB4F-27E1-44B6-8F20-9422342C1FDB>.<2> finished with error [-1017] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001979560 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <E9B2CB4F-27E1-44B6-8F20-9422342C1FDB>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <E9B2CB4F-27E1-44B6-8F20-9422342C1FDB>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/realmsdkmetrics-zmhtm/endpoint/metric_webhook/metric?data=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, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/realmsdkmetrics-zmhtm/endpoint/metric_webhook/metric?data=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, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
```

It seems I create a local realm database but it tries to connect to the remote server. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Your code is correct! No problem there. I see you opened a bug report on [Github bug #8166](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/8166) which appears to have been a back end issue with Realm and corrected. Please try to avoid cross posts like this - keep everything in one place or at least a reference to the bug report. Voting to close as it's not a bug in your code or anything we can address here on SO

Comment: @Jay ok but another reason I ask about on stack overflow is if there are any logging option to disable that behaviour. They also provide sources - maybe I could disable log on this event only and build `RealmSwift` from sources.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, there are a number of switches and alterations to XCode to prevent logging. However, that's not generally a good idea as without logging you won't know about bugs, connection issues and other important feedback about the health of your app. There are a number of options but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766783/how-can-i-disable-a-certain-oslog-log-level) for one possibility.